# How to see and manage the connected devices on your Ubuntu hotspot?

Tags: 20.04, internet, connection, hot-spot

I would like to check how many devices including mine are connected to the active hotspot, and perhaps manage the devices by kicking out unwanted devices that might be connected to my hotspot. I was surprised to find no such options avaliable in Ubuntu as almost all mobile phones have it.

Comment: "Ubuntu hotspot"? How did you set this up? Which Ubuntu release is in use? What hardware? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I am in need of a similar solution. I have created a hotspot using nmcli on ubuntu 18.04 on a Jetson Nano. I can turn on and off my hotspot from terminal and I can list the devices connected to my hotspot using arp -a but I don't know how to disconnect them. Please help